# Knockd daemon fails to start

Tags: ubuntu, security, ubuntu-14.04

I was trying to setup `knockd`, a port knocking daemon available to Ubuntu distros.

Before setting up my port knocking sequences, I decided to give a shot to the default knocking sequence, since it should open SSH to my IP address.

But when I first started the service `sudo service knockd start`, it failed with no error message and the service log located at `/var/log/knockd.log` is empty.

```
 * Starting Port-knock daemon knockd  [fail]
```

No changes have been made to the configuration, with the exception of `/etc/default/knock` where we have to change `START_KNOCKD` from `0` to `1`.

I'm most puzzled with this since the log file is literally empty.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: take a look in `/var/log/messages`. You could also investigate the service process by running it manually. You should take a look in the init script for `knockd` `/etc/init.d/knockd` and find out the command and user the service is started with.

Comment: If it's Ubuntu, you can check /var/log/syslog for possible log entry for failed service start. Also you may try to start it manually with -D (debug) and -v (verbose) options. More info here:http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/knockd.1.html

Comment: @knowhy: I don't have anything there, the folder is doesn't exist.
@bangal: That's the thing `syslog` also doesn't have any mention of knockd.

Comment: if you don't have any output at all using debug, verbose, or whatever, try to run  `sh -x /etc/init.d/knockd start` it might provide a hint on what's not working well as you'll see what's going on inside the start script

Comment: @ignivs: I've managed to solve the issue, but thanks for thr hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure it to log to syslog by changing `/etc/knockd.conf`.

Comment out `logfile = /var/log/knockd.log` under `[options]`and add following:

> UseSyslog

Then start it from shell and check output:

`knockd --debug --verbose`

More details here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/knockd.1.html

Answer (score 5):

knockd might not be finding your non-standard interface.

Specify it in /etc/default/knockd like so:

> KNOCKD_OPTS="-i eth0"

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. Thankfully verbose as mentioned in `bangal's` answer provided the clue.

Comment: This saved my bacon. I've been trying this for almost 2 days straight. Also, for future seekers - you can get your network interface by simply doing `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 3):

find the interface which case, your ip:

*ifconfig*

and add him to: **/etc/knockd.conf** example:

Interface = venet0:0